# Getting quantity from a unique Item on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spredsheet on Excel and I must get the number of items from a row, somethink like this:

```
Item1 | Qty1 | Item2 | Qty2 | Item3 | Qty3 | ... | ItemZ | QtyZ |
```

Into a second sheet, I must populate with these data, but with just two Columns (Items and Qty).

There is any way to do that? I'd rather a solution that uses `DGET` or `VLOOKUP` (it seems faster), althought any feasable way to that would make me very happy :D

I've tried use a loop function, using Find + move to the left + copy and paste the qty. The problem was that this tooked like forever (plus my Excel crashed a few times).

So folks, could you help me?

Comment: What version on Excel are you using?  

Also, are you trying to count the number of different Items listed (i.e., Item1, Item2, Item3 = 3) or the total quantity (i.e. Qty1(3) + Qty2(7) + Qty3(4) = 14)?

Comment: Can you show us what the example output would be (based on the example input you have already provided)? Right now, it's not clear what you're asking. If you can clarify, it will be easy to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're after, then here's something basic to get you started (it's in VBA, not using Excel functions, but you'll hopefully get the idea):

```
Public Sub CopyDown()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long

  j = 1
  For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 2
    Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(1, i)
    Sheet2.Cells(j, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(1, i + 1)
    j = j + 1
  Next i

End Sub
```

It's not terribly robust as there's no error checking, but it should work for the case you've described. It assumes Items are arranged across row 1 in odd columns (1, 3, etc.) and Quantities are in even columns (2, 4, etc.) in "Sheet1". Then they are copied to ascending rows (from 1 onwards) in Columns A (for Items) and B (for Quantities) in "Sheet2". Let me know if you need more explanation.